# Creating an instance of a domain class inside a grails script

Tags: grails, dns, bootstrapping

I am trying to create an instance of a domain class inside a grails 2.3.6 script:

```
def player = new Player(name:"Bob")
player.save()
```

But I keep getting an exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gaming/Player
```

I've tried all the different bootstrapping tricks I've managed to find on the internet but they don't really change the result:

I've tried importing:

```
import gaming.Player
```

I've tried loading the bootstrap script:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")
```

I've tried depending on every task I managed to find:

```
depends(configureProxy, packageApp, classpath, loadApp, configureApp, compile, bootstrap)
```

I've even tried loading the class at runtime:

```
ApplicationHolder.application.getClassForName("gaming.Player")
```

Interestingly enough, this last line doesn't barf which suggests that grails can find my class, but chooses to ignore the find when I actually go to use it.

Edit. As requested, here is the current version of the script

```
import gaming.Player

import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder

includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsClasspath")

def handleHeaderLine(line) {
    def retval = []
    line.each {
        if(!it.equals("Game Name") && !it.equals("Total # of Copies")) {
            println("Creating Player: " + it)
            def player = new Player(name:it)
            player.save 
            retval << it
        } else {
            retval << null
        }
    }
    return retval;
}

def handleGameLine(header, line) {
    println("Creating Game: " + line[0])
    for(int i = 1; i < line.length - 1; i++) {
        if(!header[i].equals("Total # of Copies")) {
            def count = line[i] == "" ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
            for(int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                println "Creating copy of " + line[0] + " owned by " + header[i]
            }
        }
    }
}

target(loadAssets: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    depends(configureProxy, packageApp, classpath, loadApp, configureApp, compile, bootstrap)

    ApplicationHolder.application.getClassForName("gaming.Player")

    def tsv = new File("...")

    def header = null;
    tsv.eachLine {
        def line = it.split("\t")
        if(header == null) {
            header = handleHeaderLine(line)
            println header
        } else {
            handleGameLine(header, line)
        }
    }
}

setDefaultTarget(loadAssets)
```

Comment: Try adding includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")

Comment: Its there already (as part of grails create-script).

Comment: could you pls provide your `Gant` script

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to do all the boiler plate effort to bring up the environment while running your script. [`run-script`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/scripts/RunScript.groovy) does that for you. When [`grails run-script`](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/run-script.html) is used following targets are run by default: `checkVersion, configureProxy, bootstrap`. And finally the script `run-script` is run.

run-script runs your custom script in `GroovyShell` by providing `ApplicationContext` and `grailsApplication` as bindings to shell. So what you would end up with your script is shown below as if it is written in Groovy console/shell:

```
//scripts/player/PlayerScript.groovy
def handleHeaderLine(line) {
    def retval = []
    line.each {
        if(!it.equals("Game Name") && !it.equals("Total # of Copies")) {
            println("Creating Player: " + it)
            def player = new Player(name: it)
            player.save(flush: true) 
            retval << it
        } else {
            retval << null
        }
    }
    return retval
}

def handleGameLine(header, line) {
    println("Creating Game: " + line[0])
    for(int i = 1; i < line.length - 1; i++) {
        if(!header[i].equals("Total # of Copies")) {
            def count = line[i] == "" ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
            for(int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
               println "Creating copy of " + line[0] + " owned by " + header[i]
            }
        }
    }
}

def tsv = new File("...")
def header = null
tsv.eachLine {
    def line = it.split("\t")
    if(header == null) {
        header = handleHeaderLine(line)
        println header
    } else {
        handleGameLine(header, line)
    }
}
```

And then use `run-script` as below:

```
grails run-script scripts/player/PlayerScript.groovy
```

which would by default run the script in dev environment. If you want for other envirnments then use as

```
grails test run-script scripts/player/PlayerScript.groovy
```

**BUT**
Due to a [major bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11216) in latest version of grails, you won't be able to run script the above mentioned way because `run-script` always depends on `bootstrap` target and would always try to bring `tomcat` up while running script as the plugin scope in `build` which would result in *Error loading plugin manager: TomcatGrailsPlugin*. The workaround is also mentioned in the defect but here is a groovier implementation. Change in `BuildConfig.groovy` as:

```
plugins {
    if ( !System.getProperty("noTomcat") ) {
        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
    }
    ....
}
```

and then issue run-script command as:

```
 grails -DnoTomcat=true run-script scripts/player/PlayerScript.groovy
```

On a side note, the reason your script was not running is that the class `Player` will not be loaded at this time while running script, for use. It has to be loaded manually using `classLoader` and then create an instance off of it. Something like:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsBootstrap")

target(playerScript: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    depends configureProxy, packageApp, classpath, loadApp, configureApp

    def playerClass = classLoader.loadClass("gaming.Player")

    //Skeptical about how a domain class would behave
    //But a normal POGO should be good being used this way
    def player = playerClass.newInstance([[name: "Bob"]] as Object[])
    player.save(flush: true)

    println player
}

setDefaultTarget(playerScript)
```