# How to run Grails script and get domain class instance

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class, grails-3.0

How to get current application environment in Grails scripts to be able to work with classes and objects like `grails console` does.
My script:

```
import security.User

List users = User.list()
users.each { User user ->
    print(user.name)
}
```

And I get an error:

```
my-script.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class security.User
```

All other manipulations from [Creating an instance of a domain class inside a grails script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996758/creating-an-instance-of-a-domain-class-inside-a-grails-script) also does not help.

I see many grails docs are stale and inconsistent.

Comment: How are running your script and where it is located?

Comment: in default scripts folder under src/main/scripts because I used create-script command. How I run it?? Hmm, already forgot,  I got a error when i just launch "grails". By the way, I see there is not "run-script" command anymore.. So how to run scripts and how to use it. This article seems to be outdated http://www.componentix.com/blog/15/execute-groovy-script-within-grails-context-updated-for-grails

Comment: possible duplicate of [run-script alternative in Grails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591547/run-script-alternative-in-grails-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails 3.x removed the `run-script` command so you have to write your own command. Here is an answer from one of the author of the Grails community:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30806256/2405040

> As an alternative, you can write an ApplicationContextCommand see for example, the schema-export command

Comment: Maybe someone can give a concrete example of that ? https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-plugins/hibernate/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/hibernate/commands/SchemaExportCommand.groovy is not clear enough to implement. I really suffering of absence  Yii.Command alternative to Grails.